# Javascript requiring a dummy call to "this" to work

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have a mighty strange JavaScript problem. I have made an object oriented maze generator, which works well, but only if I call "this" (or the alias "self") right before the generator.
See code below:

```
// Constructor for a maze
function Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight) {
    // Always working reference to this
    var self = this;

    // Has the maze been generated?
    var generated = false;

    // Default dimensions
    var width = 20;
    var height = 20;

    // Check if dimensions are given
    if (!isNaN(mazeWidth) && mazeWidth >= 1) {
            width = parseInt(mazeWidth);
    }
    if (!isNaN(mazeHeight) && mazeHeight >= 1) {
            height = parseInt(mazeHeight);
    }

    // The maze itself
    var maze = {};

    // Populate the maze
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            maze[y] = {};
            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    maze[y][x] = new MazeCell(x, y);
            }
    }

    // Function to get a cell
    this.getCell = function(x, y) {
            return maze[y][x];
    }

// For some mighty strange reason "self" (or "this") needs to be called here for the code below to work
self;
    // Generate the maze
    (function generateMaze() {
            // Map directions to its reverse
            var directionMap = {};
            directionMap[Maze.prototype.N] = Maze.prototype.S;
            directionMap[Maze.prototype.E] = Maze.prototype.W;
            directionMap[Maze.prototype.S] = Maze.prototype.N;
            directionMap[Maze.prototype.W] = Maze.prototype.E;

            // Depth-first search to generate the maze
            (function DFS(cell, entryDirection) {
                    // Set the cell as discovered and open the entry direction
                    cell._setDiscovered();
                    cell._open(entryDirection);

                    // Find the neighbour cells
                    var neighbours = {};
                    neighbours[Maze.prototype.N] = cell.getNeighbourCell(Maze.prototype.N);
                    neighbours[Maze.prototype.E] = cell.getNeighbourCell(Maze.prototype.E);
                    neighbours[Maze.prototype.S] = cell.getNeighbourCell(Maze.prototype.S);
                    neighbours[Maze.prototype.W] = cell.getNeighbourCell(Maze.prototype.W);

                    // Check the neighbour cells in random order
                    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                            var direction = (function() {
                                    var result;
                                    var count = 0;
                                    for (var direction in neighbours) {
                                            if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
                                                    result = direction;
                                    }
                                    return result;
                            })();
                            var nextCell = neighbours[direction];
                            delete neighbours[direction];
                            if (nextCell == false)
                                    continue;
                            if (nextCell._isDiscovered())
                                    continue;
                            // Set exit opening of this cell
                            cell._open(direction);
                            // Process next cell
                            DFS(nextCell, directionMap[direction]);
                    }
            })(self.getCell(Math.floor(Math.random()*width), Math.floor(Math.random()*height)), null); // This line is the problem
    })();
// ......
```

If I don't call "self" above the generation code, this.getCell will be called, but the first parameter will be a reference to the generateMaze-function itself. The second parameter will be unset.

It also work if I change the dummy line from "self" to "this".

Just writing "self" (or "this") on an otherwise empty line doesn't really do anything, does it? Why is it needed?

Comment: How did you even find out that calling `self;` fixes it. :)

Comment: Unstable code ftw, why not change your structure a little; instead of `var self` use `self` as a param in the _IIFE_ and pass in `this`

Comment: No idea how that fixes it, but in general, as it's an IIFE, would it not be more sensible to pass `self` as a parameter to the function so you don;t get any scoping issues.

Comment: I found out by trying to console.log(self.getCell) to see what it refered to. It made it work, so then I just tried to shorten it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add semicolons after assigning a value to an attribute or variable, even if the value is a function, like here:

```
// Function to get a cell
this.getCell = function(x, y) {
        return maze[y][x];
}
```

It should look like this:

```
// Function to get a cell
this.getCell = function(x, y) {
        return maze[y][x];
};
```

I think that might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Blunder on my side... Of course this is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, the function got called right after being defined. @AndriyF. makes a good point. JSHint would help a lot with this. It integrates with most IDEs. Any Javascript linter will probably warn you about these things.